# Python "for" loop, division error

Tags: python, for-loop, python-2.7

I'm using python 2.7.3
When I try

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = []
for i in a:
    b.append(1/i)
```

I'm getting an unexpected output as b = [1,0,0,0]. But if I print the value of i loop works fine.

```
for i in a:
    b.append(i)
```

will give b =[1, 2, 3, 4]
What is the reason for this. Also how I can do the same in correct way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In python 2, `/` means integer divison when both operands are integers. Try `1.0 / i`.

```
In [2]: 1 / 2
Out[2]: 0

In [3]: 1.0 / 2
Out[3]: 0.5

In [4]: 1 / 2.0
Out[4]: 0.5
```

To make the `/` operator behave like it does in python 3, use `from __future__ import division`:

```
In [11]: from __future__ import division

In [12]: 1 / 2
Out[12]: 0.5
```

Comment: or try `from future import __division__`, or Python 3.